# why this div result is different in php

Tags: php

```
$a = 116278458266472831;
echo intval($a/64); // 1816850910413638
echo intdiv($a, 64); //1816850910413637
```

when I calculate radix of a big number, I found some error, result of intval($a/64) is greater than intdiv($a, 64), could you tell me why ? maybe also you will write the deep reason, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [intval() Manual user contribution notes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php#7707)

> intval converts doubles to integers by truncating the fractional
>   component of the number.
>
> When dealing with some values, this can give odd results.

that's why you are getting `...638` in first code.

Based on [intdiv() Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intdiv.php)

> Returns the integer quotient of the division of dividend by divisor.

That's why you are getting `...637` in second code. As it returns only integer part.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to calculate precision to a variable amount and ensure your calculations are correct, you shouldn't use the functions in questions.

For such calculations you will need to use PHP's BCMath:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php